# Issue with existential in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an issue working with existentials in Scala. My problem started when creating a mini workflow engine. I started on the idea that it was a directed graph, implemented the model for the latter first and then modeled the Workflow like this:

```
case class Workflow private(states: List[StateDef], transitions: List[_, _], override val edges: Map[String, List[StateDef]]) extends Digraph[String, StateDef, Transition[_, _]](states, edges) { ... }
```

In this case class, the first two fields are a list of states which behave as node, transitions which behave as edges.

The `Transition` parameter types are for the input and output parameters, as this should behave as an executable piece in the workflow, like a function of some sort:

```
case class Transition[-P, +R](tailState: StateDef, headState: StateDef, action: Action[P, R], condition: Option[Condition[P]] = None) extends Edge[String, StateDef](tailState, headState) {
    def execute(param: P): Try[State[R]] = ...
}
```

I realized soon enough that dealing with a list of transitions in the `Workflow` object was giving me troubles with its type parameters. I tried to use parameters with [[Any]] and [[Nothing]], but I couldn't make it work (gist [1]).

If I'd do Java, I'd use a wildcard `?` and use its 'less type safe and more dynamic' property and Java would have to believe me. But Scala is stricter and with variance and covariance of the `Transition` parameter types, it's hard to define wildcards and handle these properly. For example, using `forSome` notation and having a method in `Workflow`, I would get this error (gist [2]):

```
Error:(55, 24) type mismatch;
 found   : List[A$A27.this.Transition[A$A27.this.CreateImage,A$A27.this.Image]]
 required: List[A$A27.this.Transition[P forSome { type P },R forSome { type R }]]
lazy val w = Workflow(transitions)
             ^
```

Hence then I created an existential type based on a trait (gist [3]), [as explained in this article](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/existential-types-in-scala).

```
trait Transitions {
  type Param
  type Return
  val transition: Transition[Param, Return]
  val evidenceParam: StateValue[Param]
  val evidenceReturn: StateValue[Return]
}
```

So now I could plug this existential in my `Workflow` class like this:

```
case class Workflow private(states: List[StateDef], transitions: List[Transitions], override val edges: Map[String, List[StateDef]])
  extends Digraph[String, StateDef, Transitions](states, edges)
```

Working in a small file proved to be working (gist [3]). But when I moved on to the real code, my `Digraph` parent class does not like this `Transitions` existential. The former needs an `Edge[ID, V]` type, which `Transition` complies with but not the `Transitions` existential of course.

How in Scala does one resolve this situation? It seems troublesome to work with parameter types to get generics in Scala. Is there an easier solution that I haven't tried? Or a magic trick to specify the correct compatible parameter type between `Digraph` which need an `Edge[ID, V]` type and not an existential type that basically erase type traces?

I am sorry as this is convoluted, I will try my best to update the question if necessary.

Here are the Gist references for some of my trials and errors:

1. https://gist.github.com/jimleroyer/943efd00c764880b8119786d9dd6c3a2
2. https://gist.github.com/jimleroyer/1ce238b3934882ddc02a09485f52f407
3. https://gist.github.com/jimleroyer/17227b7e334d020a21deb36086b9b978

**EDIT-1**

Based on @HTNW answer, I've modified the scope of the existentials using `forSome` and updated the solution: https://gist.github.com/jimleroyer/2cb4ccbec13620585d21d53b4431ce22

I still have an issue though to properly bind the generics with the `matchTransition` & `getTransition` methods and without an explicit cast using `asInstanceOf`. I'll open another question specific to that one issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You scoped your existential quantifiers wrong.

```
R forSome { type R }
```

is equal to `Any`, because every single type is a type, so every single type is a subtype of that existential type, and that is the distinguishing feature of `Any`. Therefore

```
Transition[P forSome { type P }, R forSome { type R }]
```

is really

```
Transition[Any, Any]
```

and the `Transition`s end up needing to take `Any`s as parameter, and you lose all information about the type of the return. Make it

```
List[Transition[P, R] forSome { type P; type R }] // if every transition can have different types
List[Transition[P, R]] forSome { type P; type R } // if all the transitions need similar types
// The first can also be sugared to
List[Transition[_, _]]
// _ scopes so the forSome is placed outside the nearest enclosing grouping
```

Also, I don't get where you got the idea that Java's `?` is "less safe". Code using it has a higher chance of being unsafe, sure, because `?` is limited, but on its own it is perfectly sound (modulo `null`).

Comment: Thanks @HTNW, that did the trick to resolve some compilation errors I could not get past. It was simpler than I thought. I was not able to make the `matchTransition` and `getTransition` work correctly without a cast to `instanceOf` though. I've created a gist with the new version: https://gist.github.com/jimleroyer/2cb4ccbec13620585d21d53b4431ce22

Do you think there is a way to avoid this cast? 

Nonetheless I feel I should accept your answer as at least, it's all working now. And I can open a new question for that specific issue. Would that be the SO standard?

Comment: Open a new question, yes.